# Transmitting electricity to a specific customer in a smart grid

Tags: bidirectional

A concept of smart grid assumes "bidirectional electricity and information flow" and "prosumers" who should be able to sell generated electricity over the grid to customers. However I do not understand when a Seller fed a certain amount of electricity into the grid, using the grid as a transmission port to "send" electricity to buyer, how the Energy Distribution Company knows that injected amount goes to a specific Buyer (allowing him to receive that electricity if he paid for it)?
Your explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Electricity is perfectly [fungible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility), so simply metering each connection to the grid (producer and consumer) is sufficient. It doesn't matter *which* electrons the consumer gets.

Comment: "It's all done on trust". The company monitoring the energy producer needs to assert that a certain quantity of energy was injected into the grid at a specific point and over a stated period and their assertion needs to be credible and believed. The "assertion" is backed up by use of certified sealed meters which can notionally be checked but the system does not need to depend on such checking occurring IF the  meter provider is "trusted"

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't track specific electricity.

Basically buyers and sellers have meters; in a "smart" grid these have a somewhat realtime data connection back to the grid operator / market maker. They declare a "spot" price, which is applied to energy going in and out.

Edit:

1. Transmission is continuous: seller injects electricity, buyer takes electricity at the same time. It's not packetised like internet or circuit switched like phones.
2. The parties can deal directly (depending on market regulation) but are dependent on the grid for transmission.
3. Correct.

(For a lot more detail on the market, have a read of http://www.uea.ac.uk/~e680/energy/energy_links/electricity/Dundee_paper_comparison_pool_bilateral_trading.pdf )

Comment: 1. So, first Seller injects electricity to the grid. Then when there is a buyer who wants to buy this energy, the grid operator transmits that energy to the buyer?

 2. Does this is mean that selling/buying parties can interact with each other only through the grid operator?

 3. So it is not possible to use a power grid as we use TCP/IP protocol, when we show destination of the packet to be transferred, and simply send a packet over TCP/IP?

Comment: I've added to the answer.